# Sort hash by key but get value

Tags: ruby

I have a hash like

```
animals = {dog: 4, cat: 5}
```

I want to sort it on the keys but get the value. Currently I have this, which feels ugly:

```
animals_sorted = Hash[animals.sort].values # 5, 4
```

Is there a prettier, more "Rubyish" way of doing it?

Comment: Why the rush in selecting an answer? Doing so may discourage other, possibly better, answers, and is a put-off for those still preparing answers a mere 15 minutes after you posted the question.

Comment: I'll remember that for next time. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
animals.sort.map(&:last)
```

Sort will produce something like this `[[:cat, 5], [:dog, 4]]`.

`map(&:last)` calls `last` on each array inside the array and will give you the final result of `[5, 4]`

Comment: Accepting this since it is slightly shorter and with an explanation. Other ruby newbs (rubes?), see http://swaggadocio.com/post/287689063/ruby-idioms-shortcuts-symbol-to-proc for ampersand explanation.

Comment: Good idea to post the link - the `&` operator is definitely one of the more confusing parts of Ruby initially! I like to think of it colloquially as 'convert to proc' because it acts the same way essentially in a method definition - except it converts a block instead of a symbol

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way using `sort_by`, `map` and `pop`:

```
> animals.sort_by{ |k, v| k }.map(&:pop)
=> [5, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
animals.values_at *animals.keys.sort #=> [5,4]
```

[Hash#values_at](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Hash.html#method-i-values_at) pulls the values from `animals` for the keys given by its arguments, in the order of the later, returning an array:

```
{dog: 4, cat: 5}.values_at *{dog: 4, cat: 5}.keys.sort
  #=> {dog: 4, cat: 5}.values_at *[:dog, :cat].sort
  #=> {dog: 4, cat: 5}.values_at *[:cat, :dog]
  #=> {dog: 4, cat: 5}.values_at :cat, :dog
  #=> [5,4]
```

I like the way this reads: "values at sorted keys".